# Integration with Riemann Sum Midpoint Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I've stucked in Java with finding Riemann Sum (Midpoint). My problem is, that I always get a wrong answer, that should be.

For example:

> a = -5, b = 12, n = 40, Result should be: 608.9107812499999 (But I get: 535.0809101562498)
>
> a = -5, b = 12, n = 200, Result should be: 609.1564312500013 (But I get: 555.8486222812485)
>
> Function is: ^2 −  + 3

Here is my code:

```
public static double intReiman(double a, double b, double n){
    double width = (b - a) / n;
    double sum = 0.0;


    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        double first_mid_p=a + width / 2.0;
        sum = sum + (first_mid_p*first_mid_p-first_mid_p+3);
    }

    return sum * width;
}


public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println(
            intReiman(-5.0,12.0,40.0)

            );
}
```

Thanks for replying!

Comment: What is the function that you are trying to calculate the integral?

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger and make sure that everything equals what you expect it to equal at each step? Learning to debug is a vital part of learning to program.

Comment: You are not using 'i' in your loop, you are doing n-times the exactly same thing, it's like : (myThing)*(n+1) so it's not very useful

Comment: I updated my post adding Function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Also, it is Riemann, not Reiman. And lastly, n should be an integer, not a double.

You missed the part of updating the first_mid_p to the correct spot (aka the part "+ i* width")

Rextester link:  http://rextester.com/FMI50088

```
public static double intRiemann(double a, double b, double n){
    double width = (b - a) / n;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        double first_mid_p=a + (width / 2.0) + i * width;
        sum = sum + (first_mid_p*first_mid_p-first_mid_p+3);
    }

    return sum * width;
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println( intRiemann(-5.0,12.0,40.0));
}
```

Comment: @yshavit Added the explanation on what was wrong in the OP code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved more efficient using functional programming in Java.
You can define the Integral as a Riemman approximation function for 1 variable as follows, where number of iterations is 100,000:

```
static final Function<Function<Double,Double>,Function<Double,Function<Double, Double>>> 
integral = f -> a -> b ->
{
    final double dx=(b-a)/100000;
    return IntStream.range(0, 100000).mapToDouble(i -> f.apply(a+i*dx)*dx).sum();
};
```

To pass the function ^2 −  + 3 use this syntax

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    double result = integral.apply(x->x*x-x+3).apply(-5.0).apply(12.0);
    System.out.println("Result is " + result);
}
```

It should print Result is 609.1579967485502

Comment: This can also be simplified using an interface public interface Riemann extends BiFunction<Function<Double, Double>, Integer, BinaryOperator<Double>>  { } and then define the integral as int N=100000;
Riemann s = (f, n) -> (a, b) -> IntStream.range(0, n).mapToDouble(i -> f.apply(a + i * ((b - a) / n)) * ((b - a) / n)).sum();